# From Datefield get months in array in django qs

Tags: django, datetime, django-queryset

I have django model with DateField.
If I need to get objects from certain month I can do this:

`objects = Model.objects.filter(date__month=8)` and it works fine, but if i do:

`objects = Model.objects.filter(date__month__in=[1, 2, 3])` I get error:

```
FieldError at /
Join on field 'date' not permitted. Did you misspell 'month' for the lookup type?
```

Is there any way to do what I'm attempting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ORM `__month` filter only does exact matching, but you could OR together several Q objects:

```
objects = Model.objects.filter(Q(date__month=1) | Q(date__month=2) | Q(date__month=3))
```

`Q` objects use the standard Python `|` operator, implemented using a custom `__or__` method for the class, so you can use `operator.or_` and `reduce` to automate the construction from an arbitrary iterable:

```
list_of_months = [1, 5, 11]
constraints = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(date__month=datenum) for datenum in list_of_months))
objects = Model.objects.filter(constraints)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Q` objects in the `filter()`, they can be used to *or* together multiple filter conditions using `|`.

The time related field lookups translates into ranges of the underlying field types, and so `__in=[...]` would not naturally translate into the underlying SQL `IN (...)`, so we are stuck with oring `Q` objects.